# Parse keypath to array item from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

How can I parse a string like this `""0.children.13.children.0"` to the path to the array item in JavaScript?
Example: `"0.children.13.children.0"` > `arr[0].children[13].children[0]`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I use Javascript

Comment: why don't you just `split(".")`? Now you have all the keys and you can resolve the value `var value = path.split(".").reduce((obj,key) => obj[key], arr);`

Comment: Thank you! Using split function is very useful in this case

Answer (score 0):

Using one string and split it on `.` could break if your objects have dots in their keys like `{'first.name':'John'}` so it would probably better to provide an array with strings/ints instead.

Here is an implementation of lodash get with the difference that it only takes path as string:

```js
var data = [
  {
    children: [
      {
        children: [{ name: 'got it' }],
      },
    ],
  },
  null,
];
const get = (object, path = '', defaultValue) => {
  const recur = (object, path, defaultValue) => {
    if (typeof object !== 'object') {
      return defaultValue;
    }
    if (path.length === 0) {
      return object;
    }
    if (object !== null && path[0] in object) {
      return recur(
        object[path[0]],
        path.slice(1),
        defaultValue,
      );
    }
    return defaultValue;
  };
  return recur(object, path.split('.'), defaultValue);
};
console.log(get(undefined, '', 'Hello World'));//defaults to hello world
console.log(get(data, 'does.not.exist', 'Hello World'));//defaults to hello world
console.log(get(data, '1', 'Hello World'));//will be null (data[0] is null)
console.log(get(data, '1.anything', 'Hello World'));//defaults to hello world
console.log(//gets item data[0].children[0].children[0]
  get(data, '0.children.0.children.0', 'Hello World'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It helped me!